# The Five Friends

Tags: riddle, wordplay, word-sequence

Once upon a time there were four friends. They hung around together, nearly always in the same order like this:

> A B C D

They were noted for their cheerful sounds.

Even on those occasions when they were out of sorts Like this:

> D A B C

They looked very happy. One day, they were joined by the twin of friend number 2. The twin always took first place and bumped the former friend 2 to third place like this:

> B A B C D

For a time, life had no meaning.

The five decided to try inviting others to lead their group. At first it was hard work,

> 1 B A B C D

so on their second try they rented a vehicle.

> 2 B A B C D

The third time, they all went for a walk.

> 3 B A B C D

The next time was almost a disaster: the lights all went out but they were soon able to put that to rights.

> 4 B A B C D

Finally, they went to the zoo and watched an animal being born.

> 5 B A B C D

These activities were so much fun that the five invitees got together and had their own party.

> 1 2 3 4 5

They had such a wild time they woke up in a completely different state!

Identify the friends.

Comment: Is it the original cast of [The BIG Bang Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory) ?

Comment: *They decided to try inviting others to lead their group.* When you say "they", do you mean the original four or including the twin? It sounds like the latter but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: @rybo111 edited for clarity.

Comment: @HughMeyers: That hint was a bit too much IMO.

Comment: @Deusovi In retrospect, I think you're right. Especially the out of sorts bit.

Comment: oh man, I totally misread the text the first time and thought it started with five friends.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The four friends are:

> RING.

ABCD

> RINGs are a type of cheerful sound.

DABC

> GRINs certainly indicate happiness,

BABCD

> IRING isn't a word - it has no meaning.

At first it was hard work,

> TIRING

so on their second try they rented a vehicle.

> HIRING a vehicle, you mean?

The third time, they all went for a walk.

> AIRING - going out into the fresh air.

The next time was almost a disaster: the lights all went out but they were soon able to put that to rights.

> WIRING would help fix the lights.

Finally, they went to the zoo and watched an animal being born.

> SIRING

They woke up in a completely different state!

> Well, something turning from solid to liquid THAWS out.

Comment: BABCD totally threw me off. Well done.

Comment: As an afterthought I just googled B A B C D and it's almost a word. Dang.

Comment: Hanging "a-round" was kind of a half-hint as well.